# Is it possible to have multiple independent transform animations?

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to run two separate keyframe transform animations on the same element but it only seems to run the last animation. Is there a way to do this?

I have tried the example in the code below ([codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WqwjaP)), as well, I've tried using position absolute on the element and animating the `top` and `left` values. It gives the effect I'm looking for, but it doesn't seem as smooth as using `translate`.

```
@keyframes animate-x {
  from { transform: translateX(0); } to { transform: translateX(100%); }
}

@keyframes animate-y {
  from { transform: translateY(0); } to { transform: translateY(100%); }
}

.element {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  transform-origin: center;
  animation:
    animate-x 20s linear infinite alternate,
    animate-y 15s linear infinite alternate;
}
```

I'm looking to run both the translateX and translateY animations simultaneously at different speeds.

Comment: you can add an extra container where you apply one of the animation

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can combine multiple transform directives into one property:

```css
@keyframes animate-y {
  from { 
    transform: translateY(0) translateX(0); 
  } 
  to { 
    transform: translateY(100%) translateX(100%); 
  }
}

.element {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  transform-origin: center;
  animation:
    /*animate-x 2s linear infinite alternate,*/
       animate-y 2s linear infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

Also, you can break up the animation by using percentages in your keyframes instead of from and to:

```css
@keyframes animate-y {
  0% { 
    transform: translateY(0); 
  } 
  25% { 
    transform: translateY(100%) translateX(0); 
  }
  
  50%{
    transform: translateY(100%) translateX(100%);
  }
  
  75% {
    transform: translateY(0%) translateX(100%);
  }
}

.element {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  transform-origin: center;
  animation:
    /*animate-x 2s linear infinite alternate,*/
       animate-y 2s linear infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

Edit: Move two directions at different speeds:

```css
@keyframes animate-y {
  0% { 
    transform: translateY(0) translateX(0%); 
  } 
  25% { 
    transform: translateY(100%) translateX(50%); 
  }
  
  50%{
    transform: translateY(0%) translateX(100%);
  }
  
  75% {
    transform: translateY(100%) translateX(50%);
  }
}

.element {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  transform-origin: center;
  animation:
    /*animate-x 2s linear infinite alternate,*/
       animate-y 2s linear infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

Comment: I guess you missed this : *I'm looking to run both the translateX and translateY animations simultaneously at different speeds.*

Comment: @TemaniAfif See my edit. I don't think you can do this the way you want to, but you can with percentage-based keyframes, if you move in one direction more gradually than the other.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, @symlink! I ended up animating the top and left values in separate animations instead